# Maths Game - returning points in methods

Tags: java, random, methods

So my objective is to create a maths game where the user selects if he/she wants a maths question from a file or a random generate one consisting of the 4 maths elements in 3 difficulties.I have created a lot of methods... I have an idea where im going but now im stuck. I need to have it so it keeps a score of questions answered correctly. How do i return the points to the main method and have the game going until the user presses 3 on the gamePlay()method
    public class MathsGameProject2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int score;
    int points = 0;
    int questionType;

    System.out.print("Please enter the what type of question you want" + "\n 1 Question from a file" + "\n 2 Random question" + "\n 3 Quit game\n");
    questionType = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (questionType != 3) {
        if (questionType == 1) {
            questionFromFile();
        } else if (questionType == 2) {
            randomQuestion();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter the what type of question you want" + "\n 1 Question from a file" + "\n 2 Random question" + "\n 3 Quit game\n");
        }
    }

}
public static questionFromFile() {

}

public static randomQuestion() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int difficulty;
    System.out.println("Please enter the difficulty you want to play." + "\n 1. Easy" + "\n 2. Medium" + "\n 3. Hard\n");
    difficulty = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (difficulty == 1) {
        easy();
    } else if (difficulty == 2) {
        medium();
    } else if (difficulty == 3) {
        hard();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1-3\n");
    }
}

public static easy() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int mathElement;
    System.out.print("What element of maths do you want?" + "\n1 Additon" + "\n2 Subtraction" + "\n3 Multiplication" + "\n4 Division\n");
    mathElement = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (mathElement == 1) {
        easyAdd();
    } else if (mathElement == 2) {
        easySub();
    } else if (mathElement == 3) {
        easyMulti();
    } else if (mathElement == 4) {
        easyDiv();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1-4\n");
    }
}

public static easyAdd() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    Random rand = new Random();

    int num = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
    int num2 = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;

    int correct = num + num2;
    int answer;

    System.out.print("What is the answer of " + num + " + " + num2 + " ?");
    answer = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (answer == correct) {
    } 
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Methods must have a return type. And that's precisely what allows them to return something to the caller method. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: I know, it is not completed as I am stuck.

Comment: You should never type as much code without even trying to compile and run it, especially if you're a newbie. Go step by step. Compile after every line you add to the code. Your code should always compile.

Comment: I was just typing out the structure then code the actual game, I went around it wrong, but it runs through the questions. I just don't have returns and don't how to get points system to work as well as run the code until the user wants to stop.

Comment: You'll find a **lot** of people around here place a good deal of importance on questioners providing [running code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... it helps us figure out what is actually wrong (since we rarely can spot the error off the bat just by looking at code), and it shows you actually made some effort first, since this isn't the place to go to have your work done for you. You'll get the best answers if you provide code that compiles and runs, and that is runnable as a standalone program.

Comment: @dcsohl Not looking for someone to do my work. I did put effort and have been spending hours trying. I've seen many bits of code on here we're the person asks on how to get a piece of code working. Mine prints out, goes to the next method when the user inputs. I just don't have method returns. I'm looking for help on how to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep track of how many questions the user answers successfully, you will need to:

1. For each question, return whether or not the user answered correctly
2. Have a counter which increments whenever a user answers a question correctly
3. Optionally, have a counter which increments whenever a question is answered wrong

For #1, you can use a boolean return value for specifying if the question was answered successfully.

```
return (answer == correct);
```

You will want to propagate that return value all the way up to the main() method.

```
static void main() {
    ....
    boolean isCorrect = randomQuestion();
    ....
}

static boolean randomQuestion() {
    ....
    return easy();
    ....
}

static boolean easy() {
    ....
    return easyAdd();
    ....
}

static boolean easyAdd() {
    ...
    return (answer == correct);
}
```

Then for #2 and #3, you can increment counter(s) defined in `main` based on the value returned by `randomQuestion()`

```
int numberCorrect = 0;
int numberWrong = 0;
....
boolean isCorrect = randomQuestion();
if (isCorrect) {
    numberCorrect++;
} else {
    numberIncorrect++;
}
```

Additionally (no pun intended), you can use a `while` loop to continuously receive user input until you get your exit code, which in this case is 3.  One way to do this is to use a `while(true)` loop and break out when the user enters 3.

```
while (true) {
    /* Get user input */
    ....
    if (questionType == 3) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Finally, after your loop, you can simply print out the value of your `numberCorrect` and `numberIncorrect` counters.

Hope this helps.